# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - could not instantiate test object

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a very strange error happening

I have a program developed in Java WEB using Hibernate to connect to the MySQL Database
The program is working correctly on several computers here but there is a computer that the program does not work!

I already tried to change the version of the server, the JDK and even the IDE and even then on this computer the program is not working

The error mentions that "could not instantiate test object" but I'm not doing any tests on any classes / objects on any computer where the project is working

Log

```
14:42:36,750 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1327)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1253)
at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250)
... 12 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : model.entity.Tabcadastro
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:62)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:136)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:557)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
at deployment.SA2021.war//model.entity.Tabcadastro.<init>(Tabcadastro.java:1)
... 34 more

14:42:36,800 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SA2021.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"SA2021.war#SA2021PU\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : model.entity.Tabcadastro
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "}}
14:42:37,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "SA2021.war" (runtime-name : "SA2021.war")
14:42:37,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
WFLYCTL0448: 142 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
14:42:37,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
14:42:37,207 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 23.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 22372ms - Started 683 of 1011 services (146 services failed or missing dependencies, 365 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:42:37,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:42:37,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:42:52,501 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'SA2021.war#SA2021PU'
14:42:52,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = SA2021.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
14:42:52,547 INFO  [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) Stopping cache manager null on null
14:42:52,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment SA2021.war (runtime-name: SA2021.war) in 65ms
14:42:52,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "SA2021.war" (runtime-name: "SA2021.war")
14:42:54,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for SA2021PU
14:42:55,123 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JIPIORMV53020253: Second level cache enabled for SA2021.war#SA2021PU
14:42:55,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'SA2021.war#SA2021PU'
14:42:55,201 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: SA2021PU
...]
14:42:55,463 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment SA2021.war
14:42:56,114 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-6) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
14:42:56,208 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JIPIORMV53020253: Second level cache enabled for SA2021.war#SA2021PU
14:42:56,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
14:42:57,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = SA2021.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
14:42:57,294 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'SA2021.war#SA2021PU'
14:42:57,299 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
14:42:57,305 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) Envers integration enabled? : true
14:42:57,379 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@26cf2ff5
14:42:57,383 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1327)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1253)
at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
at org.jboss.as.jpa@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250)
... 12 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : model.entity.Tabcadastro
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:62)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:136)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:557)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
at deployment.SA2021.war//model.entity.Tabcadastro.<init>(Tabcadastro.java:1)
... 34 more

14:42:57,426 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"SA2021.war#SA2021PU\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : model.entity.Tabcadastro
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "}}
14:42:57,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "SA2021.war" with deployment "SA2021.war"
14:42:57,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."SA2021.war#SA2021PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SA2021PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

My Tabcadastro class

```
package model.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="tabcadastro")

public class Tabcadastro implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer Id;
    
    @Column
    private String nome;
    
    @Column
    private String email;
    
    @Column
    private Integer cep;
    
    @Column
    private Integer cpf;
    
    @Column
    private String senha;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public  Integer getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(Integer cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public Integer getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(Integer cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

My Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SA2021PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.entity.Tabcadastro</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bancodreambk?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently, in a web app with relatively basic java code for entity persistence to a database, restful web services, and web UI code and supporting files such as images, for testing the restful services. The code was stable and functioned properly for several years, but after upgrading the environment and dev tools and rebuilding, I started getting an error during deployment to wildfly. The server produced the same stack trace - except originating from a different entity class - during deployment as described in this issue, on both wildfly 22 and 23, and a similar but not identical error on wildfly 11.

Eventually I found that the built-in deploy function in Netbeans fails, but building a war file and deploying it by hand to wildfly 23 succeeds. Specifically, the deploy function in netbeans deploys the project as a folder, projectname.war, and it fails to deploy properly in wildfly. Building the same project sources into war file in netbeans, projectname.war, and then deploying that war file by hand, by simply dropping it in the standalone deployment folder, succeeds. Whether the problem reported in the original post is due a similar issue is difficult to determine.

p.s. Here's the environment for my case:

- windows 10
- Apache Netbeans 12.3
- adoptopenjdk's jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot
- wildfly (multiple versions tested)
- postgresql 13 database running on the same box
- postgresql jdbc driver 42.2.20
- minimal persistence.xml referencing a jndi data source configured in wildfly

Comment: Thanks, 
It really is the built-in deploy function in Netbeans that is the problem, generating the .war and deploying it manually everything works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the constructor of `Tabcadastro` throws a `RuntimeException`. Did you recompile your code? Are you using some kind of Java Agent that transforms the constructor somehow?

Comment: Yes, it was recompiled and we are not using any Java Agent to generate the constructor method, so the Tabcadastro class does not have a constructor method. We even tried to create an empty constructor method just to see if the error disappeared but it still persists

This error is bothering us a lot, because it only happens on this computer, on all other computers it works correctly. We tried to delete everything and create it again, but the error still persists

Comment: If this just happens on a specific computer, I would try to recreate the environment (JDK, IDE, workspace, etc.) to rule out issues due to that.

Comment: We tried:
JDK 15, JDK 8
Netbeans 12.0, Netbeans 12.3
Wildfly 22, Wildfly 23
I'll share the codes
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfpE-cpHJiiFpS7bRI3VQK0bR6qWn2GY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but I am not willing to invest hours of investigation for this. Maybe you can ask Red Hat support for help on this?